# how to get sum of every objects by queryset (object by object )

Tags: python, django, sum, aggregation, annotate

i have no expernce with 'aggregation' and 'annotate' and talk with exemple better
i have this object :

```
mediasec = MediaSec.objects.filter(date__range=[primary1, primary2], degraycomany__in=degraycompsec)
```

if i print it after convert it to list and loop will get this dict :

```
{'id': 5, 'degraycomany_id': 5, 'nomberhisas': 3, 'date': datetime.date(2020, 9, 25)}
{'id': 8, 'degraycomany_id': 5, 'nomberhisas': 1, 'date': datetime.date(2020, 9, 27)}
{'id': 9, 'degraycomany_id': 5, 'nomberhisas': 1, 'date': datetime.date(2020, 9, 27)}
{'id': 10, 'degraycomany_id': 5, 'nomberhisas': 1, 'date': datetime.date(2020, 9, 27)}
{'id': 13, 'degraycomany_id': 5, 'nomberhisas': 3, 'date': datetime.date(2020, 9, 28)}
{'id': 7, 'degraycomany_id': 6, 'nomberhisas': 2, 'date': datetime.date(2020, 9, 27)}
{'id': 11, 'degraycomany_id': 6, 'nomberhisas': 1, 'date': datetime.date(2020, 9, 27)}
{'id': 6, 'degraycomany_id': 7, 'nomberhisas': 1, 'date': datetime.date(2020, 9, 27)}
{'id': 12, 'degraycomany_id': 7, 'nomberhisas': 1, 'date': datetime.date(2020, 9, 28)}
{'id': 14, 'degraycomany_id': 7, 'nomberhisas': 3, 'date': datetime.date(2020, 9, 28)}
{'id': 15, 'degraycomany_id': 8, 'nomberhisas': 1, 'date': datetime.date(2020, 9, 28)}
```

so now i want to get sum of every degraycomany_id so i use this queryset:

```
test1 = MediaSec.objects.filter(date__range=[primary1, primary2], degraycomany__in=degraycompsec).aggregate(Sum("nomberhisas"))
```

the rusult come :

```
{'nomberhisas__sum': 18}
```

i want reslt like this :

```
{'id': 13, 'degraycomany_id': 5, 'nomberhisas': 9, 'date': datetime.date(2020, 9, 28)}
{'id': 11, 'degraycomany_id': 6, 'nomberhisas': 3, 'date': datetime.date(2020, 9, 27)}
{'id': 14, 'degraycomany_id': 7, 'nomberhisas': 5, 'date': datetime.date(2020, 9, 28)}
{'id': 15, 'degraycomany_id': 8, 'nomberhisas': 1, 'date': datetime.date(2020, 9, 28)}
```

i want get sum of 'nomberhisas' in every 'degraycomany_id' not the sum of all object

the models :

```
class MediaSec(models.Model):
    degraycomany = models.ForeignKey(DegreyCompany, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nomberhisas = models.SmallIntegerField()
    date = models.DateField()
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=1, null=1)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
class DegreyCompany(models.Model):
    withdegrey = models.ForeignKey(Degrey, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Secondary, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    spesial = models.ForeignKey('Spesial', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=withdegrey.name, null=True, blank=True)
    nomberetud = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    nomberexist = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    femail = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    reatrap = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Can you provide the relevant models? `MediaSec` and `DegrayComany`?

Comment: i set it now ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i try this queryset :

```
        test1 = MediaSec.objects.filter(date__range=[primary1, primary2], degraycomany__in=degraycompsec).values('degraycomany_id').annotate(total_price=Sum('nomberhisas'))
```

the ruslt come :

```
<QuerySet [{'degraycomany_id': 5, 'total_price': 9}, {'degraycomany_id': 6, 'total_price': 3}, {'degraycomany_id': 7, 'total_price': 5}, {'degraycomany_id': 8, 'total_price': 1}]>
```

this is near from what i want maybe help

Comment: add date to values too, if you want it to aggregate by date also